# Can I teach Google that when I say “Java”, I mean “Java 6”?

Tags: google-search

I use Google a lot to look for Java documentation.

Example: If I want to find documentation for `HashMap`, I just google `Java hashmap` and Google knows to redirect me to the `javadoc` page.

However, it usually directs me to Java 1.4 or Java5 documentation, and I want Java6 documentation.

If I google `Java 6 hashmap`, it works fine; the problem is I keep forgetting to put `6` and have to search twice.

Can I teach Google somehow that when I say `Java`, I mean `Java6`? (I have a Google account, so if it is somehow configurable via an account, I'm open for suggestions.)

Comment: I suggest `hashmap site:download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs` as replacement instead.

Comment: @Daniel Beck: Seems like an overkill. I want to type less, not more :)

Comment: You could just create a keyword search in your browser: `http://search.oracle.com/search/search?search_p_main_operator=all&group=Documentation&q=%s+url%3A%2Fjavase%2F6%2Fdocs%2Fapi` where `%s` is replaced by the keyword. For example, `hashmap`.

Comment: [You think you have it bad ...](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/103570/can-i-teach-google-search-that-when-i-say-javascript-i-dont-mean-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for all the answers - I eventually solved it by creating my own custom search engine in Chrome (partial solution to the problem I posted - but a full solution for my personal problem).

The search engine is defined as: **https://www.google.com/search?q=java%206%20%s**
And I assigned it the keyword `java` - that way all I need to type in the address bar is `java hashmap` and I get the result I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem/wish. This is what I did to solve it:

- Install [this Greasemonkey script](http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/12844) (which is a bit out of date, since it was made before Oracle bought Sun)
- Edit the script slightly to make it work with Oracle's website. This is the edited script:

  ```
  // ==UserScript==
  // @name           Java 6 Documentation Redirect
  // @namespace      http://freecog.net/2007/
  // @description    Redirects to the Java SE 6 documenation from older pages.
  // @include        http://download.oracle.com/javase/*
  // ==/UserScript==

  var old_loc = loc = window.location.href;
  loc = loc.replace(/\/javase\/[^\/]+\/docs\//, "/javase/6/docs/");
  if (loc != old_loc) window.location.replace(loc);
  ```

The only changes are to the `@include` URL and the regex.

That way, whenever you open a Java documentation page, it redirects to the Java 6 version. If you ever really need to see an older version, you can temporarily disable the user script.

Comment: Using this for Java 7, the CSS there is much better.

Answer (score 1):

I have a search keyword with the URL of

```
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/%s.html
```

Then I just have to type in the name of the class replacing `.` with `/`. I type this into my browser:

```
j java/util/HashMap
```

You can also use Duck Duck Go — it will onebox Java classes, and it appears to consistently choose Java 6:

> http://duckduckgo.com/?q=java.util.HashMap