# Can I teach Google Search that when I say "JavaScript", I don't mean "Java"?

Tags: google-search

When I did a google search for "switch statement javascript uncommon", I got two hits about the unrelated language Java on the first page.

[image]

Can I somehow teach Google Search to not confuse the two words? Alternatively, is there a better search keyword to use than "javascript", such as "JS"?

Comment: "Alternatively, is there a better search keyword to use than "javascript", such as "JS"?" Just a tip: if you insert "JS" in the search term, Google will replace it with "javascript". It won't get you better results, but the upside is that you get to type a few less strokes every search.

Comment: I tried recreating your scenario and I got completely different results - is this a consistent behaviour you see on your browser? Are you logged in to a google account? If yes - have you tried logging out and checking the results?

Answer (score 6):

Add `-java` to the search term. The character `-` is the equivalent of the [logical NOT operator on Google search](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433?hl=en).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Andrew Grimm and would like to add that you can search for specific words by using quotes. Such a search will also be case sensitive, though, so be aware of that. Personally, in searching for JavaScript-specific topics, I normally just add js or JS to the end of my search string.